# Mapping Synapse data flow with parameterized dynamic source need importing projection dynamically

Tags: azure-data-factory, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

[image]

I am trying to build a cloud data warehouse where I have staged the on-prem tables as parquet files in data lake.

I implemented the metadata driven incremental load.

In the above data flow I am trying to implement merge query passing the table name as parameter so that the data flow dynamically locate respective parquet files for full data and incremental data and then go through some ETL steps to implement merge query.

The merge query is working fine. But I found that projection is not correct. As the source files are dynamic, I also want to "import projection" dynamically during the runtime. So that the same data flow can be used to implement merge query for any table.

In the picture, you see it is showing 104 columns (which is a static projection that it imported at the development time). Actually for this table it should be 38 columns.

Can I dynamically (i.e run-time) assign the projection? If so how?
Or anyone has any suggestion regarding this?
Thanking

Muntasir Joarder

Comment: How are you addressing column names in your transformations if the projection changes?  If there is always a common set of columns with a dynamic source, then remove the projection and use byName() to address column names instead. That will make your data flow as flexible as possible with full schema drift support and late column name binding.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Schema drift in your source transformation when the metadata is often changed. This removes or adds columns in the run time.

The source projection displays what has been imported at the run time but it changes based on the source schema at run time.

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift#main) for more details with examples.